# Installing node modules with node-gyp spawn ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to install the dependencies of the node-rtp-midi module.
I followed the tutorial on the node-gyp github and searched the internet for many hours. I just can't get this thing to work.
Every time a module needs node-gyp, the installation of the dependencies fails.
Bellow you can find a screenshot with the cmd output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVyN4.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- Visual Studio 2012 installed
- Windows SDK installed
- Python 2.7 installed
- node.js version 0.10.26
- node-gyp version 0.13.0

Comment: Did you try from the special Widnows SDK command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I get the the same output there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install rtpmidi-node on a Windows machine, you should install the Apple Bonjour SDK

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the PYTHON EnvVar to a full path including the executable!
The PATH Variable is not enough.

set PYTHON=c:....Python\2.7.4\python.exe

Otherwise node-gyp finds the correct path and executes the found path, not the executable. The result is the ENOENT.